# CSS Square Thumbnail Preview before upload

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a sign up form with an image upload. When a user selects an image, a preview of it will appear. I want it to appear square. This works fine when the image is landscape, however portrait images are not square.

I want to add a class to the preview image (.portrait) if the image is portrait. And then have this class removed if the user decides to change the image to a landscape.

This code is working fine, apart from the class being changed.

Thank you.

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#profile-image-preview').html('<img src="' + e.target.result + '">');
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
    }
  }
}


function imageOrientation() {

  $('#profile-image-preview img').each(function() {
    if ($(this).width() > $(this).height()) {

      $(this).addClass('landscape');

    } else {

      $(this).removeClass('landscape');

    }
  });

};

$("#imageUpload").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
  imageOrientation();
});
```

```css
#profile-image-preview {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#profile-image-preview img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#profile-image-preview img.portrait {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="imageUpload" style="margin: 15px 0; display: block;" />
<div id="profile-image-preview"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `setTimeout(imageOrientation,100)` on the function to make it refresh on change and setting it to a small value so its **not noticeable**. Make use of a flag variable which gets initialized to 0 onchange and after running the function twice returns from the function. *(Make sure to initialize the **flag to 0** when onchange is triggered)*

```
if (flag == 1)
    return;
  flag = 1;
  setTimeout(imageOrientation, 100);
```

Along with that define seperate classes for **portrait** and **landscape** with *respective height and width*:

```
#profile-image-preview.landscape {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

#profile-image-preview.portrait {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```js
var flag;
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#profile-image-preview').html('<img src="' + e.target.result + '">');
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
    }
  }
}


function imageOrientation() {
  $('#profile-image-preview img').each(function() {
    if ($(this).width() > $(this).height()) {
      $(this).removeClass('portrait');
      $(this).addClass('landscape');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('portrait');
      $(this).removeClass('landscape');
    }
  });
  if (flag == 1)
    return;
  flag = 1;
  setTimeout(imageOrientation, 100);
};

$("#imageUpload").change(function() {
  flag = 0;
  readURL(this);
  imageOrientation();
});
```

```css
#profile-image-preview {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#profile-image-preview img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#profile-image-preview img.landscape {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

#profile-image-preview img.portrait {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="imageUpload" style="margin: 15px 0; display: block;" />
<div id="profile-image-preview"></div>
```

Comment: @SSAM No problem :)